# Must GTK "callbacks" be static functions?

Tags: c, callback, gtk3

In all of the gtk examples I've read, callbacks are always static functions. I think I remember reading somewhere that there is a reason for that, but I can't find it now.

Must GTK callback functions be static? How come? What would go wrong if I defined them in a different control unit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Nothing bad will happen if you make your callback functions not static.